# Kruskal Wallis for binary data

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

I have collected data from three groups (with different sizes of n). This was done with a test instrument consisting of 9 items, each binary coded (1 = right, 0 = wrong). The results are not equally distributed.

I now want to show that there is a signifikant difference between the three groups for the total score of the test (min = 0, max = 9), but also for the single items.

I did a Kruskal-Wallis for the total score and the results were promising. Now I am unsure if I can use the same test for the individual items because they only have binary values (0 and 1).

So, is it useful to do a Kruskal-Wallis for binary data?
Is there any other test I could use?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like a [chi-squared](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chisq.htm) test for your different groups? You'd have your marginals determined on one axis, but it should be a decent fit for the situation you're describing.